# .htaccess code broke site?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal

I tried to add a new .htaccess file to the root of a Drupal site with the following code:

```
# Redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but now I get this error on every page that is not the homepage. Please HELP! So if I go to www.website.com/products I get this:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /products was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.website.com Port 443
```

Is this "Not Found" related to the .htaccess code above?

Comment: I think that's unlikely to be the cause. That snippet is only there to force `www.` in the domain name. It's not doing anything more that, except that it doesn't attempt to add a `www.` prefix if the request ends in something that looks like a file.extension.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought it may just be coincidental that I noticed the error the same time I added the .htaccess, but I wasn't sure. If mod_rewrite wasn't turned on, if adding the .htaccess would have messed things up and Apache would need a restart?

Comment: Yes, if you used this without having `mod_rewrite` enabled and then you enabled, a restart would be required for that change to kick-in; i.e., to load the new module. That said, under normal circumstances you don't need to restart Apache following edits to your .`htaccess` file, no.

Comment: By "adding new .htaccess file" you mean that you added this code to existing (Drupal's) .htaccess file or you replaced old one with yours?

Comment: @MilanG I actually accidentally overwrote the Drupal `.htaccess` file because it was hidden file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the issue here was that I uploaded an `.htaccess` file and didn't see the one that was already there because the file was ***hidden*** on the server, so I actually accidentally overwrote the Drupal `.htaccess` file that was there by mistake. Once we reverted to the original `.htaccess` file and added this code to it, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 is normally used to HTTPS. The best way to handle that is with vhosts. Using the vhost route, you would try something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

Going the .htaccess route, you may want to try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```